# How can I fix the slowness of my pygame event loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm creating a button class for a game, and I'm using the pygame event loop to detect mouse clicks (specifically when the mouse is released) (I hear it is better the method of using `pygame.mousemget_pressed()[0]`). However, the event loop seems to be slow, not responding and performing the buttons function when it is clicked. I think it may be because relate to how I created the event loop in a class, but I'm not sure. Here's a sample of my code:

```
class Button:
    """A Button class, built for all kinds of purposes"""
    def __init__(self, window, rect, message, off_color, on_color, message_color, message_font_size):
        pass # just a bunch of variables that use the parameters given

    def in_button(self):  
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if pygame.Rect(self.rect).collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            return True

    def clicked(self):
        if self.in_button():

            pygame.event.pump() 
            for e in pygame.event.get():
                if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    return True
# I proceed to create 5 instances using this class.
```

I removed some unnecessary method information in my code. If you need anything more, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the `clicked` method in a different way, because there should be only one event loop in your application, not one in every button instance. [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) empties the event queue, so calling it multiple times per frame will cause problems.

I suggest to pass the events to the buttons. In this (very simple) example I pass the `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events to the `clicked` method and then check if the  `event.pos` (mouse position) of the event collides with the rect. If it returns `True`, I do something in the event loop in the main function.

```
import pygame as pg


class Button:

    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.image = pg.Surface((100, 40))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

    def clicked(self, event):
        """Check if the user clicked the button."""
        # pygame.MOUSE* events have an `event.pos` attribute, the mouse
        # position. You can use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` as well.
        return self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    button = Button((100, 60))
    number = 0

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Pass the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event to the buttons.
                if button.clicked(event):
                    number += 1  # Do something.
                    print('clicked', number)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        screen.blit(button.image, button.rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

If you want a button with several images, you can use something similar to the button class [here (the first addendum)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664205/6220679) or search for more sophisticated Button classes for pygame.