# Quit python program with a button and a callback method

Tags: python, pygame

I feel like I'm making a dumb error, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Here is the code:

```
class menu:
    hover = False
    def __init__(self, text, pos):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.set_rect()
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        self.set_render()
        screen.blit(self.render, self.rect)

    def set_render(self):
        self.render = subFont.render(self.text, True, self.get_color())

    def get_color(self):
        if self.hover:
            return (BLACK)
        else:
            return (GREEN)

    def set_rect(self):
        self.set_render()
        self.rect = self.render.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

select = [menu("Computer Virus", (100, 200)),
          menu("Computer Crime", (100, 300)),
          menu("QUIT", (100, 400))]
running = True
while running:
    for evnt in event.get():  
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill(WHITE)    
    title()
    for menu in select:
        if menu.rect.collidepoint(mouse.get_pos()):
            menu.hover = True               
        else:
            menu.hover = False
        menu.draw()
    pointer()
    display.update()
```

but the program would just crash. 
How can I make it so that I can quit the screen when clicked on quit?

Comment: I added the full source code up above, I didn't want to spam the question with code. [link](https://github.com/ChewyCarrot/menu) 
(HomePage>"Untitled-1.py")

Comment: Please don't post links to your projects, because they could disappear or be changed in the future. Add the relevant code to your question instead.

Comment: I've already prepared an example for you, but there are some differences to your program (it shouldn't be a problem to adjust it to your liking). BTW, I called the `menu` class `Button` because it's really a button not a menu. Also, take a look at the [PEP 8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quit your game, you can define a function or method in which you set the `running` variable to `False` and then pass it to one of the button instances as the `callback` function.

Here's a more object-oriented example with an `App` class that has a `self.running` attribute and a `quit_game` method. If the user clicks on the button, the `quit_game` method gets called, `self.running` is set to `False` and the main while loop will stop.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
# Global constants.
WHITE = pygame.Color('white')
GREEN = pygame.Color('green')
BLACK = pygame.Color('black')
FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)


class Button:

    def __init__(self, text, pos, callback):
        self.text = text
        self.callback = callback
        self.image = FONT.render(self.text, True, GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    self.callback()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.image = FONT.render(self.text, True, BLACK)
            else:
                self.image = FONT.render(self.text, True, GREEN)


class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.select = [
            Button("Computer Virus", (100, 200), lambda: print("Computer Virus")),
            Button("Computer Crime", (100, 300), lambda: print("Computer Crime")),
            Button("QUIT", (100, 400), self.quit_game),
            ]

        self.running = True

    def quit_game(self):
        self.running = False

    def main_loop(self):
        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                for button in self.select:
                    button.handle_event(event)

            self.screen.fill(WHITE)

            for button in self.select:
                button.draw(self.screen)

            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)


app = App()
app.main_loop()
pygame.quit()
```

---

If you don't want to use the `App` class, you can also write a function which changes the global `running` variable. However, note that global variables are usually frowned upon because they make code harder to read and more error prone (in this case it's not that dramatic).

```
def quit_game():
    global running
    running = False

# Pass it as the `callback` argument.
Button("QUIT", (100, 400), quit_game)
```

Comment: The main loop is inside of the class, so I'm assuming that I would have to add all the other events in that loop (which is in the class)?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question? I'm not sure what you mean. I use the `for button in self.select:` loop in the event loop to pass all events to the `handle_event` methods of the button instances.

Comment: BTW, here's a similar [answer (first addendum)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664205/6220679) with a slightly more complex `Button` that demonstrates how to use pygame sprites and sprite groups to create buttons.