# Pygame won't quit after calling the function

Tags: python, function, pygame, exit, exit-code

I'm having some trouble while trying to quit from a function that I made. It just doesn't seem to break the loop. The game opens and I can play around but I can't quit, It just stays there without doing anything and the icon on the task bar goes full yellow.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame, os, sys, math

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
grey = (128, 128, 128)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
def game_menu():
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.init()

    pygame.display.set_caption(".")

    menu = True
    events = pygame.event.get()
    while menu:
        for event in events:
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              menu = False
              pygame.quit()
              quit()


    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(black)

    font = pygame.font.Font('MATRIX.ttf',60)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("MATRIX PASA PALABRA", font,white)
    TextRect.center = ((600/2),(50))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    #Jugar

    button("Jugar",300,200,200,50,None)
    button("Instrucciones",300,275,200,50,None)
    button("Dificultad",300,350,200,50,None)
    button("Salir",300,425,200,50,None)
    pygame.display.update()
def text_objects(text, font,color):
     textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
      return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

     events = pygame.event.get()

     if x+w> mouse[0] > (x) and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,grey,(x,y,w,h))
        for event in events:
            if event.type ==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and msg=="Salir":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and msg=="Jugar":
                None
     else:
          pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,white,(x,y,w,h))
          smalltext= pygame.font.Font("MATRIX.ttf",30)
          textsrf,textrct=text_objects(msg,smalltext,black)
          textrct.center = ((x+(w/2)),(y+(h/2)))
          gameDisplay.blit(textsrf,textrct)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   game_menu()
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please post a [complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One thing that you shouldn't do is to call `pygame.display.set_mode` every iteration of the while loop. Do that once before the while loop starts.

Comment: Ok I added all the functions that I used for game_menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is that you call `pygame.event.get` multiple times per frame. The event queue will be emptied after the first call, so the events won't get processed correctly. There should be only one `pygame.event.get` call per frame.

To fix this problem, you can assign the list of events that `pygame.event.get` returns to a variable in the main while loop and then pass it to the `button` function.

```
while menu:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        # etc.

    button("Jugar",300,200,200,50,events,None)
```

Add an `events` parameter to the `button` function:

```
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,events,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if x+w> mouse[0] > (x) and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,grey,(x,y,w,h))
        for event in events:
            # etc.
```

BTW, this `button` function keeps popping up here again and again, probably because it's a really bad way to implement buttons. I'd recommend a solution similiar to one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664205/6220679 or search for pygame GUI toolkits (SGC is pretty good).

---

The others have already mentioned that the indentation in your example is wrong and that `sys.exit` is a better way to quit than the `quit` function.

Here's a fixed, complete example:

```
import pygame, os, sys, math

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
grey = (128, 128, 128)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


def game_menu():
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.init()

    pygame.display.set_caption(".")
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    menu = True
    while menu:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              menu = False
              pygame.quit()
              sys.exit()

        DISPLAYSURF.fill((30, 30, 30))

        font = pygame.font.Font(None,60)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("MATRIX PASA PALABRA", font,white)
        TextRect.center = ((600/2),(50))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        #Jugar

        button("Jugar",300,200,200,50,events,None)
        button("Instrucciones",300,275,200,50,events,None)
        button("Dificultad",300,350,200,50,events,None)
        button("Salir",300,425,200,50,events,None)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


def text_objects(text, font,color):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def button(msg,x,y,w,h,events,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if x+w> mouse[0] > (x) and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,grey,(x,y,w,h))
        for event in events:
            if event.type ==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and msg=="Salir":
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and msg=="Jugar":
                print("jugar")
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,white,(x,y,w,h))
        smalltext= pygame.font.Font(None,30)
        textsrf,textrct=text_objects(msg,smalltext,black)
        textrct.center = ((x+(w/2)),(y+(h/2)))
        gameDisplay.blit(textsrf,textrct)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   game_menu()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been stuck with this for hours, now I can keep going. Thx for the recomendation too!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try adding `pygame.display.quit()` before the line `pygame.quit()`. This should close any open displays.</strike>

Edit:
The problem is that most of your program isn't inside the while loop. Most importantly, the `events = pygame.event.get()` isn't inside the while loop so the events are never updated.

Rearranging the code to something like this should work:

```
def game_menu():
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption(".")

    menu = True

    while menu:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(black)

        font = pygame.font.Font('MATRIX.ttf',60)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("MATRIX PASA PALABRA", font,white)
        TextRect.center = ((600/2),(50))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        #Jugar

        button("Jugar",300,200,200,50,None)
        button("Instrucciones",300,275,200,50,None)
        button("Dificultad",300,350,200,50,None)
        button("Salir",300,425,200,50,None)
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in events:
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              menu = False
              pygame.quit()
              quit()
```

Comment: I created a new tab to test this without using a background image and it seems to work. But then I try to use it in the original and the game just doens't close.

Comment: it works on the new module that I made just for trying this but it doesn't work on the whole program. I think it might be the button func but I still can't close the program with the X on the window.

Comment: It works on my computer. My guess would be that you're calling pygame.event.get() multiple times in each loop, first in the while loop, then 4 more times when you call the function button. Try deleting that line from the button function and instead pass the events in as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, what you said was the same thing that the other guy said but I'm a beginner so I didn't understand you very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you import `sys` then you can use that to exit your code.

```
import sys
def game_menu():
    menu = True
    while menu:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you in? I'm using 3.6 and it works for me.

Comment: I'm using 3.6 too