# How to implement button interaction for Main Menu (Pygame)

Tags: python, button, menu, pygame, program-entry-point

I've been watching a bunch of tutorials and new to pygame and coding in general. None of the tutorials I watched helped me with this. What i'm aiming for is for the buttons to change the button to a different colour when the user hovers over the button. Below is my entire code for the main menu so far.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

size = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)


pygame.display.set_caption("Basketball Shootout")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#GAME INTRO

def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

#Font's and text
font = pygame.font.SysFont ("Times New Norman", 60)
text = font.render ("", True, WHITE)

#Background Image
background_images = pygame.image.load("greybackground.jpg").convert()
screen.blit(background_images, [0,0])
screen.blit(text, (150, 50))

#Background Music
pygame.mixer.music.load('game.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.constants.USEREVENT)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(15)

#BUTTONS
screen.blit(text, (150, 50))
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(300,300,205,80));
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(300,400,205,80));
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(300,500,205,80));

font = pygame.font.SysFont ("Times New Norman, Arial", 30)
text = font.render ("START", True, WHITE)
screen.blit(text, (340, 320))
font = pygame.font.SysFont ("Times New Norman, Arial", 30)
text = font.render ("OPTIONS", True, WHITE)
screen.blit(text, (340, 420))
font = pygame.font.SysFont ("Times New Norman, Arial", 30)
text = font.render ("ABOUT", True, WHITE)
screen.blit(text, (340, 520))

pygame.display.flip();

#Quit Pygame
game_intro()
pygame.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing the button data (text surface, rect, color) in a list of lists. When the mouse moves, `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` events get added to the event queue. In the event loop check if the mouse moved and then iterate over your buttons and set the color of [colliding buttons](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to the hover color, reset the others to black. Blit the rects and text surfaces in a for loop as well.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
HOVER_COLOR = (50, 70, 90)
# Don't define new font objects in your while loop (that's inefficient).
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont ("Times New Norman", 60)
# If the text surfaces and button rects don't change,
# you can define them once outside of the while loop.
text1 = FONT.render("START", True, WHITE)
text2 = FONT.render("OPTIONS", True, WHITE)
text3 = FONT.render("ABOUT", True, WHITE)
rect1 = pygame.Rect(300,300,205,80)
rect2 = pygame.Rect(300,400,205,80)
rect3 = pygame.Rect(300,500,205,80)
# The buttons consist of a text surface, a rect and a color.
buttons = [
    [text1, rect1, BLACK],
    [text2, rect2, BLACK],
    [text3, rect3, BLACK],
    ]

def game_intro():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                for button in buttons:
                    # button[1] is the rect. Use its collidepoint method with
                    # the `event.pos` (mouse position) to detect collisions.
                    if button[1].collidepoint(event.pos):
                        # Set the button's color to the hover color.
                        button[2] = HOVER_COLOR
                    else:
                        # Otherwise reset the color to black.
                        button[2] = BLACK

        screen.fill((20, 50, 70))

        # Draw the buttons with their current colors at their rects.
        # You can unpack the button lists directly in the head of the loop.
        for text, rect, color in buttons:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
            screen.blit(text, rect)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(15)


game_intro()
pygame.quit()
```

I'd actually recommend defining a `Button` class, but I'm not sure if you're already familiar with classes/object-oriented programming.

The buttons also need callback functions to actually do something. Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664205/6220679

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped a lot, although I am having trouble changing the background image. When I tried to implement your code into my own source it would only show me the background image and wouldn't show the buttons.

Comment: You probably have to rearrange the drawing section of your code. Blit the background first, then the buttons and finally call `pygame.display.flip()`. By the way, you only need to call `pygame.display.flip` or `pygame.display.update` once per frame.

Comment: Thanks it finally works, i'm starting to use the callback functions

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a function for this:

```
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        gameDisplay.blit(active, (x, y))
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(inactive, (x, y))
```

and then in you game intro call you function like this:

```
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        # For example
        button(100, 350, 195, 80, startBtn, startBtn_Hover)
```

This is what each parameter means:

- x: x-coordinate of button
- y: y-coordinate of button
- w: width of button
- h: height of button
- active: picture when mouse is hovered over button
- inactive: picture when button is idle